# hadoop storage directory uses space more than total data on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

i have a three node hadoop cluster with **replication factor** = 3.

**Storage Directory** is **/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/** for each system.

Each **datanode system** has hard-disk capacity of 221GB.

the **Effective data** of HDFS is 62GB with **replication** 62*3= 186GB.

Now the problem is i am falling short of storage even though i have only 186GB of data on 660 GB cluster:
HDFS  shows huge difference in the space available for use:

datanode1 =7.47 GB

datanode2 =17.7 GB

datanode3 =143 GB

to make sure that these space is used by hadoop local storage, i ran this command on each datanode.
for datanode1

```
du -h --max-depth=1 /app/hadoop/tmp/
63G     /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs
139G    /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred
201G    /app/hadoop/tmp/
```

for datanode2

```
du -h --max-depth=1 /app/hadoop/tmp/
126G    /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred
62G     /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs
188G    /app/hadoop/tmp/
```

for datanode3
       du -h --max-depth=1 /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/
    62G     /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data
    62G     /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/

**here datanode1 has used 201GB space for storage.**
I tried load-balancer but its showing the cluster is balanced.
here is the output.

```
start-balancer.sh
starting balancer, logging to /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/logs/hadoop-ocpe-balancer-blrkec241933d.out
Time Stamp               Iteration#  Bytes Already Moved  Bytes Left To Move  Bytes Being Moved
The cluster is balanced. Exiting...
Balancing took 622.0 milliseconds
```

recently one of my datanode went down for few days, after fixing it this problem has arisen.
How to balance the load?

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis of disk space includes MapReduce scratch directory space (/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred paths), which lie outside of HDFS and are mostly temporary data cleared upon job completion. 
The DFS space (/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs) seems to be consistent with your expected usage size.

Therefore, your disk space isn't being hogged by the DataNodes, rather by the TaskTrackers - and restarting them forces a clearing of those directories.